# Multiple sites on apache2 server

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I'm trying to serve multiple sites on the same ip. These are the configurations under /etc/apache2/sites-available

**Default Config:**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            # This directive allows us to have apache2's default start page
            # in /apache2-default/, but still have / go to the right place
            RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    ServerSignature On

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

**First site:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin techm3@gmail.com
ServerName site1.ws
ServerAlias *.site.ws

# Index file and document Root (where the public files are located)
DirectoryIndex index.html
DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/site1.ws/htdocs"

# Custom log file locations
LogLevel warn
ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/site1.ws/log/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/site1.ws/log/access.log combined

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/site1/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

**Second site:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin techm3@gmail.com
ServerName me.site2.com
ServerAlias me.site2.com

# Index file and document Root (where the public files are located)
DirectoryIndex index.html
DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/site2.com/htdocs/"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/site2.com/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

Whenever I try to load site2 it gives me the content of site1. What am I doing wrong?

**Note:** I'm redirecting a Godaddy's domain and subdomain to my server ip on port 80.

Comment: Shoot, I had the same problem and I can't remember how I fixed it. Do you have another `VirtualHost` or `ServerName` somewhere?

Comment: @minitech
in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf I have ServerName localhost

Comment: Are there only the site1 and site2 vhosts in your `/etc/apache2/sites-available` file? What's the URL you are using to load site2?

Comment: Both, site1 and site2 configurations files are in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and were enabled using `a2ensite`and both `DocumentRoot` are different.

Answer (score 0):

Register your both sites in /etc/hosts file